# Moment of inertia around rotation point

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can somebody help me how to calculate the moment of inertia of a plate with two attached boxes around a rotation point?

I know the lengths to each center of mass and the mass of each object but I am not sure how to calculate the moment of Inertia around point O.
If the length to each center is called r can I calculate the inertia as:

<$I = m1 \cdot r1 + m2 \cdot r2 + m3 \cdot r3$>

[image]

Comment: You normally need to calculate the mass moment of intertia about a rotation axis. What worries me is that you described m2 as a plate. Is the rotation plane on screen?

Comment: The rotation is around the axis perpendicular to the screen in the rotation point O an m2 is a plate along the same axis

Comment: Are the 6 numbers $m1, m2, m3, r1, r2, r3$ the **only** data given to you ?

Comment: I got the length along the plate and perpendicular to the plate as well

Comment: Even if $m1, m3$ can be approximated as point masses, assuming $m2$ to be a point mass may introduce significant error if the proportions in the attached figure are to be believed. If length, breadth and width of $m1, m2, 3$ are available to you, you should use them in your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

$I = m_1 \cdot r_1^2 + m_2 \cdot r_2^2 + m_3 \cdot r_3^2$

Comment: This assumes that the three objects are point masses.

Comment: If more information was present, OP should have used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem